# Displaying coordinates of polygon vertex in kinetic.js on mousehover

Tags: kineticjs

I have a simple code of polygon from the kinetic.js documentation.

`var poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
        points: [73, 192, 73, 160, 340, 23, 500, 109, 499, 139, 342, 93],
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 5
      });`

I need to show coordinates of the polygon on mouse hover on the vertex of polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to your poly with `poly.on(eventtype,callbackFunction)`:

You can get all your poly's points with `poly.getPoints()`

```
poly.on("mouseover",function(){
    console.log(poly.getPoints());
});
```